# Where is the source code for Linux built in Services?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I am looking at linux startup services, like Cron which runs at level 5 located in init.d, in the startup script I can only see the script file and location of binary file which is executed on startup.

Where can I see the actual source code of these services?

Comment: Exactly how will depend on your distribution. RPM-based and DEB-based systems should be able to install the source version of the package from the repositories.

Comment: Linux is not an operating system.  Technically, it's a kernel, but in common use it's a family of operating systems, mostly similar.  If you'd specified Ubuntu or Fedora or some other distro (read OS) name, we could have helped you directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Debian (or Debian based) systems, you can also `apt-get source <packagename>`, assuming you have the appropriate `deb-src` URLs in `/etc/apt/sources.list`.

This works for underprivileged users, it will fetch the source and uncompress it in the current working directory.

To reproduce the builds, its a good idea to have `debhelper` installed, or let apt satisfy the dependencies automagically by using `apt-get build-dep <packagename>`

Its a lot more convenient than googling / searching for the source archive that will reproduce the version of the program you want to study or modify.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your distribution, but Debian has source packages for each package, e.g. http://packages.debian.org/source/lenny/cron